Take value of nearest (L1) non-zero in three dimensional array
I wish to fill all zero valued elements of a three-dimensional numpy array with the value of the "nearest" non-zero valued element (at the point of running the program.)  I do not mind which is used when there are multiple with the same distance.
I can demonstrate the desired result in 2D:
input:
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 0
0 3 4 0
0 0 0 0

output:
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4
3 3 4 4

input:
1 0 2 0
0 3 0 1
2 0 4 0

a valid output:
1 2 2 2
3 3 2 1
2 3 4 1

I guess the best I've thought of myself is to take each non-zero index in turn and fill neighboring zero valued elements with that value, and repeat until no non-zero elements remain.  Which would take ages.  This will be running on arrays of size ~ 256,256,256 so being fast would be good.
[EDIT] This works, and is not too slow for use actually.  Still would be nice to find a solution without the for loop:
is_useful_value_data = np.isin(actual_data, values_we_want_to_preserve)
indices = np.where(is_useful_value_data)

interp = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(indices, actual_data[is_useful_value_data])

indices_to_fill = np.where(~is_useful_value_data)

for index in np.transpose(indices_to_fill):
    x = index[0]
    y = index[1]
    z = index[2]
    nearest_val = interp([x,y,z])
    actual_data[x,y,z] = int(nearest_val)


Consider scipy.ndimage.distance_transform_cdt, like: arr[tuple(distance_transform_cdt(arr == 0, metric="taxicab", return_indices=True, return_distances=False))]
